# I can't install FIFA 13 on my laptop

Tags: technical-issues, fifa-13

I bought FIFA 13 and installed it on PC. Now when i try to install it on my laptop and enter the key it says that the key is already used. what should i do to install it on laptop?

Comment: Where are you entering the key? Is it [Origin](https://www.origin.com/) or some installer?

Comment: while installing fifa 13 from cd it asks for cd key in installation process

Comment: According to your other question, your FIFA 13 [is linked to your Origin account](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129272/what-should-i-do-before-selling-my-used-fifa-13-to-someone-else).  I'd suggest installing that on your laptop, and use that to get the game working.

Comment: report the issue to your retailer...

Comment: @fbueckert I tried as u told by installing it from origin bt it asks to download game there so is there a way by which I can install it from origin without downloading as I dont have that much time to download it....

Comment: @devansh You obviously had 24 hours to wait for no answer here, why didn't you just start the download meanwhile?

Comment: Though if Origin works anything similar to Steam, your PC installation should provide a "backup installed games" function that you can then restore on your laptop